# Azure Self Hosted Integration Runtime - Security Concerns

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

If I want to host a self hosted integration runtime to process data on my local network, and just use ADF a data manipulation tool rather than something that submits data to the cloud, will it ever be sent up to Azure to be processed?

It appears to be that the data would solely be processed on the nodes of the Self Hosted Integration Runtime, but wanted to confirm.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure Data Factory including Azure Integration Runtime and Self-hosted
> Integration Runtime does not store any temporary data, cache data or
> logs except for linked service credentials for cloud data stores,
> which are encrypted by using certificates.

The Self-Hosted IR is Hybrid Scenario. You can implement additional security features like Storing credentials in Key-Vault, using different ports, different data encryption techniques (IPSec VPN or Azure ExpressRoute) during transit.

Refer: [Security considerations for data movement in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-movement-security-considerations#hybrid-scenarios)